# Symfony2 get public services in controller

Tags: service, dependency-injection

Much ink has flowed about Sf2 controller/container. I face with follow situation:

```
app/console container:debug security
...
> 4
[container] Information for service security.token_storage
Service Id    security.token_interface
Class         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token ...
...
Public        yes
```

## LoginBundle\DefaultController.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        dump(Controller::get('security.token_storage'));
    ...
```

works OK, obviously.

## LoginBundle\UserUtilsController

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class UserUtilsController extends Controller
{
     public function getRoleById()
     {
     dump(Controller::get('security.token_storage'));
     ...
```

throw: **`Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object`**

In [Sf2 Book - Service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) I found:

> *In this example, the controller extends Symfony's base Controller, **which gives you access to the service container itself. You can then use the get method to locate and retrieve the my_mailer service from the service container**.*

The misunderstanding is: 
- Both controllers extends basic controller which itself extends ContainerAware which implements ContainerAwareInterface which set container. 
- Both controllers access same public service container.

So, why the second controller it doesn't work?

I know that the question is old but I don't want to inject a controller as service and I think it is redundant and wrong to redeclare a public service in services.yml

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself and I want to share for every one is in same situation...
The UserUtilsController doesn't work because it's not working in this manner. The Symfony architecture is interesting if you get to know it.

## LoginBundle\Controller\UserUtilsController

```
// For this job we don't need to extends any class..
class UserUtilsController
{
   // but we need a property for injecting the service in it
   private $token;

   // Now let's inject service into our property $token
   public function __construct($token) 
   {
     $this->token = $token;
   } 

   // It's not done but let pretend it is and let's use it
   public function getRoleById()
   {
     ...
     return $this->token->getToken()->getRoles(); 
     ...
```

## services.yml

```
   #here it's the magic
   services: 
       # this is a new services container 
       user.loggeduser_utils:
            # this is my class (second class)
            class: LoginBundle\Controller\UserUtilsController
            # this is how I feed my _construct argument
            arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

So I just inject an existing service in my new class.

Now, to use this we must to call in first class:

## LoginBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
     // because my class is now a service container we call in this way
     $userRoleId = $this->get('user.loggeduser_utils');
     ...
```

This solution above is almost trivial simple AFTER understanding the Sf2 DI model.